# PATH entry deletes itself after restart?

Tags: path

Every time I want to start docker, I have to run PATH=$HOME/.docker/bin:$PATH. Then, until restart docker command will work via terminal. After restart, I have to manually add it to $PATH again. Anyone encountered this and knows a solution?

Comment: You simply have to edit your path appropriately.  It’s in `.zshrc`or `.zprofile`